# Tomcat servlet will not complete websocket connection

Tags: apache-2.4, websocket, tomcat9

I am moving a set working servlets from one server to another

```
Old server, Centos6, Apache 2.2, Tomcat 9
New Server, Centos7, Apache 2.4, Tomcat 9
```

I have about 5 servlets running from the old server all are OK, except the one servlet that has 3 websocket connections. Everything else runs in the servlet but the websockets.

Tomcat is reverse proxied behind apache.

My configuration for one of the reverse proxies

```
# websocket proxy
<Location "/admin/AdminConsole">
 ProxyPass  wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
 ProxyPassReverse wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
 Require all granted
</Location>
```

Output from apache error_log  LogLevel debug proxy:trace5

```
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.963246 2020] [proxy:trace2] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(1985): [client 174.30.215.226:46978] http: found worker http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole for http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.963335 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] mod_proxy.c(1123): [client 174.30.215.226:46978] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.963372 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2203): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.963388 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2256): [client 174.30.215.226:46978] AH00944: connecting http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.966024 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2426): [client 174.30.215.226:46978] AH00947: connected /admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.966077 2020] [proxy:trace2] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2768): HTTP: fam 10 socket created to connect to localhost
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.966734 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2802): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.966781 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2942): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.972425 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: http: has released connection for (localhost)
```

The last line says 'http' released connection?  is that apache?

```
[Wed Jul 01 23:10:45.972425 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 25640] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: http: has released connection for (localhost)
```

Output from apache access_log a 404

```
174.30.215.226 - - [01/Jul/2020:23:10:45 -0400] "GET /admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web HTTP/1.1" 404 473 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0" 1611 1025
```

It appears that maybe apache is dropping the connection?  But why?

I removed the reverse proxy connecting to tomcat directly at URL:8080 and the websockets were fine.

It appears Apache reverse-proxy from 2.2 to 2.4 is screwing the pooch.

Edit # 1

Here are the logs (LogLevel debug)of a working 2.2 server and my new 2.4 server during revers proxy

```
This is the new server
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.812027 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 53009] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(972): [client 174.30.215.226:38854] AH01076: url: http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.812040 2020] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 53009] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(975): [client 174.30.215.226:38854] AH01077: declining URL http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.812062 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2203): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.812078 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2256): [client 174.30.215.226:38854] AH00944: connecting http://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.813819 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2426): [client 174.30.215.226:38854] AH00947: connected /admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.814389 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2802): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.814476 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2942): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.818830 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 53009] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: http: has released connection for (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:39:27.819281 2020] [deflate:debug] [pid 53009] mod_deflate.c(849): [client 174.30.215.226:38854] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 1096 to 457 : URL /admin/AdminConsole

This is the old working server
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(91): [client 174.30.215.226] canonicalising URL //localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(1508): [client 174.30.215.226] proxy: wss: found worker wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole for wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy.c(1028): Running scheme wss handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1963): proxy: HTTP: declining URL wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(388): [client 174.30.215.226] AH02451: serving URL wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(2013): proxy: WSS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(2069): proxy: connecting wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(2195): proxy: connected /admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(2446): proxy: WSS: fam 2 socket created to connect to localhost
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] proxy_util.c(2578): proxy: WSS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(236): [client 174.30.215.226] sending request
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(254): [client 174.30.215.226] setting up poll()
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(299): [client 174.30.215.226] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(308): [client 174.30.215.226] AH02446: sock was readable
[Thu Jul 02 13:33:11 2020] [debug] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(175): [client 174.30.215.226] wstunnel_transfer complete
```

The most obvious difference is the 2.2 working server is proxying to a wss: address while the 2.4 broken server is proxying to a http: address.  I don't know if that is a logging bug or an error on the proxy service.  I don't see wstunnel being used at all in the broken server?

Edit #2

Finally a brake through of sorts.

I noticed that the proxy_fcgi was being called on the web-socket address and failing, so I removed it's LoadModule and now proxy_wstunnel was called though it failed with a [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]

So I enabled SSProxyEngine at the top of the reverseProxy.conf

SSLProxyEngine on

It now gets even farther, actually connecting the websocket but it fails in the SSL module:

Here is the log

```
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180768 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy.c(1123): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH01143: Running scheme wss handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180823 2020] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_http.c(1930): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL wss://localhost:8080/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180842 2020] [proxy_scgi:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_scgi.c(517): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH00865: declining URL wss://localhost:8080/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180857 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(336): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH02451: serving URL wss://localhost:8080/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180874 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2203): AH00942: WSS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.180889 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2256): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH00944: connecting wss://localhost:8080/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.182986 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2426): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH00947: connected /AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web to localhost:8080
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.183216 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2802): AH02824: WSS: connection established with [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.183269 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2942): AH00962: WSS: connection complete to [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.183293 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 61402] [remote ::1:8080] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server mbepapers.org:443)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.188928 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 61402] [remote ::1:8080] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189045 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 61402] SSL Library Error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189063 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 61402] [remote ::1:8080] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server mbepapers.org:443)
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189113 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 61402] [remote ::1:8080] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189154 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(257): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189167 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(266): [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH02446: sock was readable
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189180 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 61402] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(131): (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 174.30.215.226:42470] AH02442: error on sock - ap_get_brigade
[Thu Jul 02 17:55:49.189234 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 61402] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: WSS: has released connection for (localhost)
```

Almost there!!!!
now proxy.c is Running the wss sceme and the address of the URL is

wss://localhost:8080/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=web

Which is the URL my client has always sent!

**The error is in the SSL module**

```
[Thu Jul 02 23:53:57.947613 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 7910] [remote ::1:8080] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Thu Jul 02 23:53:57.947758 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 7910] SSL Library Error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
[Thu Jul 02 23:53:57.947778 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 7910] [remote ::1:8080] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server mbepapers.org:443)
[Thu Jul 02 23:53:57.948036 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 7910] [remote ::1:8080] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
```

SSL Library Error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Looking for a solution???

edit 3

I can connect to this server using https:/IP  because the old server that this is replacing is using the correct DNS IP<-> domain name. I installed the certificates form that server becasue I will be swapping IP's soon.  I wonder if that is the reason for the error?

edit 4

Still looking for a solution to this.  When I try to proxy the websocket I get this error in the httpd error_log with loglevel debug

```
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.978213 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] mod_proxy.c(1123): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH01143: Running scheme wss handler (attempt 0)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.978266 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9147] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(336): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH02451: serving URL wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=app
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.978302 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2203): AH00942: WSS: has acquired connection for (localhost)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.978323 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2256): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH00944: connecting wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=app to localhost:8080
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.980603 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2426): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH00947: connected /admin/AdminConsole?userName=derricks&source=app to localhost:8080
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.981093 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2802): AH02824: WSS: connection established with [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.981205 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2942): AH00962: WSS: connection complete to [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.981355 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server www.mbepapers.org:443)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983594 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983814 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] SSL Library Error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983871 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server www.mbepapers.org:443)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983907 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983969 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9147] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(257): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH02445: woke from poll(), i=1
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.984005 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9147] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(266): [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH02446: sock was readable
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.984019 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:debug] [pid 9147] mod_proxy_wstunnel.c(131): (103)Software caused connection abort: [client 174.30.215.226:54434] AH02442: error on sock - ap_get_brigade
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.984092 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9147] proxy_util.c(2218): AH00943: WSS: has released connection for (localhost)
```

the pertinent lines

```
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983594 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH02003: SSL Proxy connect failed
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983814 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] SSL Library Error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983871 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server www.mbepapers.org:443)
[Sat Jul 11 14:27:23.983907 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9147] [remote ::1:8080] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
```

It was suggested I move the reverse proxy inside the vhost section so here that is

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
 RewriteEngine on
 ServerName www.mbepapers.org
 ServerAlias www.mbepapers.org
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProxyEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /var/www/httpd-cert/mbepapers.org.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/httpd-cert/mbepapers.org.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/httpd-cert/intermediate.crt
 SSLCaCertificateFile /var/www/httpd-cert/intermediate.crt

 ProxyRequests off

 <Location "/admin/AdminConsole">
   ProxyPass  wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
   ProxyPassReverse  wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
   Require all granted
 </Location>
```

Comment: What software is listening on localhost port 8080? What is its configuration?

Comment: tomcat is at 8080

Answer (score 0):

Well the fix was very simple.  I changed the reverseproxy to use the un-secure websocket connection to my tomcat server

this caused a failure in SSL proxy authentication

```
# websocket proxy
<Location "/admin/AdminConsole">
  ProxyPass  wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
  ProxyPassReverse  wss://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

this circumvents the need for SSL proxy authentication

```
# websocket proxy
<Location "/admin/AdminConsole">
  ProxyPass  ws://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
  ProxyPassReverse  ws://localhost:8080/admin/AdminConsole
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

From the client I am using the secure websocket address which apache now proxys to a unsecure websocket. This is ok because I'm secure across the internet, and only unsecure on my local host.

here is the connection address on the client

```
WSuri = new URI("wss://"+host+"/admin/AdminConsole?userName="+userName+"&source=app");
```

Still odd that apache 2.2 had no problem, but 2.4.6 does. Though I read a few posts that indicated 2.4.6 had problems with secure proxy.

Comment: "This is ok because I'm secure across the internet, and only unsecure on my local host.".. I'm living in a parallel universe I guess